# Is there a limit to the number of rows that can be added to a DataTable in c#?

Tags: c#, datatable

I am fetching data from excel file, decoding the SAML requests and then storing the decoded requests in a DataTable - all done in C#.

The problem is that when I count the number of rows that have been added to the DataTable using this code:

```
int totalRows = table.Rows.Count;
```

The output is not the same as the number of rows in the actual excel file. I was just wondering if there is a limit to the number of rows that can be added from excel file to a DataTable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **The maximum number of rows that a DataTable can store is 16,777,216.**

You can find more information on MSDN: [DataTable Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)